# Ошибка повторного нажатия кнопки

Tags: android, kotlin, android-alertdialog

Всем привет, есть такой код, который генерирует кнопку и окно для ввода текста

```
    val alert = AlertDialog.Builder(this)

    alert.setTitle("Определение размеров таблицы.")
    alert.setMessage("Укажите количесво строк:")

    val input = EditText(this)
    alert.setView(input)

    alert.setPositiveButton("Ok") { dialog, whichButton ->
        val value: String = input.getText().toString()
        // Do something with value!
        userCounter=Integer.parseInt(value)
        while (0 < userCounter) {
            tableLayout.addView(RowCreate())
            userCounter--
        }
    }

    alert.setNegativeButton(
        "Отмена"
    ) { dialog, whichButton ->
        // Canceled.
    }

    val butt=Button(this);
    butt.text="Добавить строки"

    butt.setOnClickListener() {
        alert.show()
        
    }
```

Проблема в том, что при повторном нажатии приложение вылетает. В логах есть такая ошибка `java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.`

Я понимаю, что нужно удалить из `alert` editor-а, но не могу понять как это сделать.

Comment: Непонятно кто именно этот `child`, который `already has a parent`. Можете привести полный stack trace ошибки?

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:5264)
at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:5093)
at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:5062)
at com.android.internal.app.AlertController.setupCustomContent(AlertController.java:682)
at com.android.internal.app.AlertController.setupView(AlertController.java:546)
at com.android.internal.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:277)

Comment: Что у вас tableLayout и RowCreate() дополните вопрос

Comment: Не могли бы вы показать, как выглядит ваш диалог?

Comment: Там один EditText в окне диалога и кнопка "Отмена". @Наталья, может вы просто `alert.dismiss()` забываете когда надо вызывать?

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja компилятор ругается на alert.dismiss()

Comment: @Style-7 tableLayout таблица, RowCreate() функция для добавления строк. Она работает, не думаю, что проблема в них

Comment: @iramm код представлен выше. Если на словах, то это окно, куда пользователь вводит цифру (15 к примеру) и в таблицу (tableLayout) добавляется 15 строк

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog#dismiss()

Comment: Вылетает при повторном нажатии на что? (диалог, кнопка в активности или фрагменте) у вас кнопка создается btn а как она "присоединяется" не показано.

Comment: @Style-7, извиняюсь за неполноту вопроса. Интересует вот эта кнопка, которая вызывает `alert`                          `butt.setOnClickListener() {alert.show()}`

Comment: Всем спасибо, разобралась. Просто вынесла создание диалогового окна в отдельную функцию и вызвала где нужно